# Create a new plist from the existing plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, plist

**I have a plist like in the below first  image ,thats my main plist** and in that the field **"bid"** is unique . i have the value of bid **(for example  bid=90)** then i need to search the value in all entries of my main (first image)plist  **and create a new plist&  retrieve the corresponding values(bid,description,category,rating)** belongs to that plist .How can i do this?

**EDIT**

if i have multiple values with me like bid =88 and another bid=90  then **i have to create a new plist from the main plist (as shown in first  image)** then the result should be like **image 3**

[image: First image-main plist]

[image: Final out put iam expecting]

[image: image3-new result]

Comment: Plists are basically xml, I'd suggest an XML parser.

Comment: no yar i have to use plist

Comment: So you want to do this at runtime? Create a new plist for every item and then get the values for bid, description etc... ?

Comment: no  no only create one more plist.

Comment: Please check updated image and EDIT part in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainPlistFile" ofType:@"plist"];
//path has path for main plist.

NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentOfFile: path];
NSArray *listbook = [dictionary objectForKey:@"listbook"];

for (NSDictionary *item in listbook) {
if ([[item objectForKey:@"bid"] isEqualToString yourNSStringWithBidToSearch]) {
//now item is the desired dictionary, you can get values by using objectForKey
//or write it to a file like below.
[item writeToFile:pathToSaveNewPlist automatically:NO];
break;
     }
}
```

Remember you will have to first create the NSString pathToSaveNewPlist and yourNSStringWithBidToSearch, I'll leave that to you.

---

---

So you edited the question :
Lets assume you have an NSArray bidsToSearch which has NSStrings of the bid values to be searched :

```
NSMutableArray *targetListbook = [[NSMutableArrray alloc] init]];
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mainPlistFile" ofType:@"plist"]];
for (NSDictionary *item in [dictionary objectForKey:@"listbook"])
    if ([bidsToSearch containsObject:[item objectForKey:@"bid"]])
        [targetListbook addObject:item];
[@{listbook:targetListbook} writeToFile:pathToSaveNewPlist automatically:NO];
```

Comment: final values are correct but final plist is not creating ,why so?

Comment: i created NSMutableDictionary and add the targetListbook with key "listbook" instead of this statement @{listbook:targetListbook}.now its working

Comment: Oh, my bad, little mixup, I didn't have Xcode then. My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSPropertyListSerialization` class to serialize and deserialize property lists.

EDIT: below is some pseudo code for how to do it.

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistFile]; // read file
id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data ...]; // deserialize
// do your work
data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plist2 ...]; // serialize
[data writeToFile:plistFile2 ...]; // write to file
```